# Microsoft Azure EventServiceException

Tags: sql, azure

[Image From Azure](https://i.stack.imgur.com/qoQAO.png)

While in the Microsoft Azure SQL Database Activity log page, I came upon this error / warning.

```
"{\"Code\":\"InternalServerError\",\"Message\":\"Exception of type 'Microsoft.Azure.Event.Common.EventServiceException' was thrown.\"}"
```

Any idea what this means?

Comment: did you get this resolved.. me too getting this issue

Answer (score 0):

I am getting it when upload a .pfx file in azure domain services

Comment: Welcome to SO. What are you getting? Do you mind to explain better your problem? Please read this [doc](https://stackoverflow.com/help/how-to-ask) in order to improve your question

Answer (score 0):

I am not sure what resolved the problem, but the error message simply disappeared after a few days. I am not really sure what happened, but I am assuming it is temporary.

Since it says "EventServiceException" I am assuming it could be some sort of maintenance on the server.